# unsubscribe to the Rxjs finalize operator

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, rxjs, firebase-storage

Q: I have a question here. `finalize` operator has been called when the source has finished or complete the Observable. That is clear. But how can we predict will it not emit value again due to change on Source observable? Or `finalize` will terminate the Original Observable after completing its first emit. i.e. no more emits from the source like `take(1)`.

I use [AngularFireStorage module](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/storage/storage.md#example-usage) to download the Url. I need to complete the observable after it returned the URL. How can I do that? i.e. without unsubscribing to the subscription here.

Will this work or a better way? How can I automatically unsubscribe after fetching the download URL?

```
     afUploadTask.snapshotChanges().pipe(take(1), finalize(() => this.downloadURL 
= afStorageReference.getDownloadURL())).subscribe();
```

This is the original example from the doc:

```
task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
        finalize(() => this.downloadURL = fileRef.getDownloadURL() )
     )
    .subscribe()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your goal is to wait for the upload task to complete and then set the url. you could do exactly as in the example or like so:

```
afUploadTask.snapshotChanges().subscribe(
  null,
  null,
  () => this.downloadURL = afStorageReference.getDownloadURL()
);
```

this would also be equivalent:

```
afUploadTask.snapshotChanges().pipe(last()).subscribe(
  () => this.downloadURL = afStorageReference.getDownloadURL()
);
```

adding the `take` operator will cause a premature completion before the url is available. You don't need to worry about unsubscribing as the observable will complete when the upload completes. A completed observable will not prevent garbage collection or cause memory leaks.

Comment: I hope I need to use `finalize` anyway since the official doc gave it that way. Please see here: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/storage/storage.md#example-usage

Comment: The key thing here is I need a downloadable URL here. Without it meaningless.

Comment: ok... i think you're going about it wrong, why are you trying to add `take(1)`

Comment: Yes, that is the question here. I would like to have a better way here to automatically unsubscribe. Otherwise memory leaks and etc.

Comment: memory leaks are not a concern with completing observables. a completion is equivalent to unsubscribing. if finalize runs or the completion handler runs, the observable is done and eligible for garbage collection

Comment: I have a question here. `finalize` operator has been called when the source has finished or complete the Observable. That is clear. But how can we predict will it not emit value again due to change on Source observable? Or `finalize` will terminate the Original Observable after completing its first emit. i.e. no more emits from the source like `take(1)`.

Comment: A source that has completed cannot emit anymore, that’s part of the observable contract. Finalize only runs upon completion. Which only occurs at most once in an observables life cycle. Finalize doesn’t terminate anything, it just runs once the observable terminates itself.

Comment: Okay, that means I do not need to write any `unsubscription` code here if I'll use this way no? `afUploadTask.snapshotChanges().pipe(finalize(() => this.downloadURL 
= afStorageReference.getDownloadURL())).subscribe();`

Comment: Correct. That is equivalent in all behavior to both observables in my answer